# LWJGL - Simple lighting

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, lighting

i want to code a little minecraft clone. Now i tried to insert some simple lighting but my results are very bad. I read much about it and i tried different solutions without any result.

Thats what i got.

Initializing:

```
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Config.GAME_WIDTH, Config.GAME_HEIGHT);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
    GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
    GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Modelview Matrix

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_CULL_FACE);
    GL11.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CCW);

    GL11.glLightModeli(GL11.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_LOCAL_VIEWER, GL11.GL_TRUE);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHTING);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_LIGHT0);

    FloatBuffer qaAmbientLight  = floatBuffer(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    FloatBuffer qaDiffuseLight  = floatBuffer(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    FloatBuffer qaSpecularLight = floatBuffer(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, qaAmbientLight);
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, qaDiffuseLight);
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_SPECULAR, qaSpecularLight);

    FloatBuffer qaLightPosition = floatBuffer(lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z, 1.0f);
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_POSITION, qaLightPosition);
```

So now before each render i tried this:

```
    GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_FLAT);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    FloatBuffer qaLightPosition = floatBuffer(lightPosition.x, lightPosition.y, lightPosition.z, 1.0f);
    GL11.glLight(GL11.GL_LIGHT0, GL11.GL_POSITION, qaLightPosition);

    FloatBuffer ambientMaterial = floatBuffer(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    FloatBuffer diffuseMaterial = floatBuffer(0.8f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f);
    FloatBuffer specularMaterial = floatBuffer(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);


    GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_AMBIENT, ambientMaterial);
    GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_DIFFUSE, diffuseMaterial);
    GL11.glMaterial(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SPECULAR, specularMaterial);
    GL11.glMaterialf(GL11.GL_FRONT, GL11.GL_SHININESS, 50.0f);
```

Of course this is not much code but this is all about lighting. Did i make a mistake? I read that OpenGL is not as good as DirectX for lighting and shadowing.

That's what it looks like:

http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/7014/testrender.png

Can someone give me tips to get it a better look?

I found one post with an awesome block landscape. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ3Dx.jpg
That's how it should look like :)

Comment: Don't use deprecated functions!

Comment: Did not know they are deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone give me tips to get it a better look?

Neither OpenGL nor DirectX have nothing to do with lighting and shadowing, if you use programmable pipeline.  The normals become just another vertex attribute, which can be used for lighting computation. Fixed functionality is old and deprecated, and thus not recommended, if you aren't forced to use it.

Changing to shaders isn't really that hard, and you won't be limited by the fixed pipeline anymore; you have then complete control over how the lighting is computed, you can easily output more debug information (such as coloring surfaces based on their normals).

> That's how it should look like :)

The screen you posted has also visible [ambient occlusion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_occlusion). Achieving this effect without shaders would be extremely hard and simply not worth the effort.

I happen to be doing a similar project myself; I wouldn't mention it, if it wasn't OpenSource and publicly available. Here's the sample result:

[image: Minicraft Screenie]

You can find the lighting shader code [here](https://github.com/bananu7/MiniCraft/blob/master/Data/shaders/main_cubes.vert).

I'll post an excerpt to prevent links from rotting:

```cpp
float CalcDirectionalLightFactor(vec3 lightDirection, vec3 normal) {
    float DiffuseFactor = dot(normalize(normal), -lightDirection);

    if (DiffuseFactor > 0) {
        return DiffuseFactor;
    }
    else {
        return 0.0;
    }
}

vec3 DiffuseColor = Light0.Color * Light0.DiffuseIntensity * CalcDirectionalLightFactor(Light0.Direction, normal);
```

Comment: First let me thank you for your great post. I have never done anything with shaders. So i think its the best time to have a look into it. Your clone looks very nice to me and thats what mine should looks like.

Comment: I checked out your shader and simulated it with RenderMonkey. The cubes are very dark. I read a lot about shaders but i did not found one for the pic I post (http://i.imgur.com/zIocp.jpg). My problem is to do this wihtout a texture only with grey colors. Have you some advice for me to get it? Thank you.

Comment: @user2246718 if they are very dark, you probably forgot to turn on SRGB framebuffer.

Comment: hm I tried it in RenderMonkey. I do not know how to turn it on in RenderMonkey or if it is default on. Thats what I got http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/2386/renderrest.png

Comment: Verify that all the normals are correct, that you ignore the texture or supply it correctly. Debugging graphics is hard

Answer (score 1):

Bartek's answer is a good one.  You will want to go down the path of writing your own shaders, understanding what OpenGl provides for shadowing and lighting and not relying on older, deprecated lighting models.  It is a lot more complex the glEnable(LIGHTING_AND_SHADOWING).

But, if you just want to play with your code to see the colors change from binary black/white, one potential idea is turning off the qaSpecularLight (which creates "glossy" all-white highlights that don't help you get to a "matte" look) and adjusting the glShadeModel setting for SMOOTH shading.

That should help somewhat, but will not get you all the way to your goal.  Follow Bartek's suggested path (or google for similar ideas).

Comment: Thank you for your tipps. I already played with the setting even with SMOOTH. After that I decided to post this question because I would not get an acceptable result without any help. I see thats more complex but if I want good results I have to learn it.